# sql query for latest record in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table like following:

```
EmployeeName -----    date       ------ seqno

  A            10-02-2014                2
  B            10-02-2014                1
  C            10-01-2014                1
  D            10-02-2013                2
  E            10-02-2013                1
```

Now whenever a new employee is added on the same date the seq no is added to 1 more.. suppose one more employee is added for 10-02-2014 the seq num becomes 3 .. so `i need the latest record with max sequence number` .. i was able to do to this using rownum as:

```
select * from employee where rownum=1 order by date,seqno DESC;
```

Is this correct ??

Is there a way to do this without using rownum ?

Comment: Do you want the record for max sequence number for each date or at all?

Comment: @hamlet no not for each date but the latest date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a subquery

```
select * from employee e
where date = 
     (Select Max(date)
      from employee)
   and seqno = 
     (Select Max(seqno)
      from employee
      where date = e.date)
```

The query you show should specify desc for both date and seqNo....
(If you don't specify, the query processor assumes ascending.)

```
select * from employee 
where rownum=1 
order by date desc, seqno DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rownum` by this approach. The `rownum` is formed in `FROM clause` thus ordering will change the number sequence. You must use subquery to get correct result.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *
   FROM employee
   ORDER BY date DESC, seqno DESC
) A
WHERE rownum = 1
```